# Implementing a min/max function in Scheme

Tags: list, scheme, max, min

I need to write a function for class in Scheme that finds the minimum and maximum value in a list. We are not allowed to use the built in min and max functions. I found a segment of code that finds the max and min values, but for me it outputs the minimum as the head of the list. Here is the code:

```
(define (minmax lst)
  (cond
    ((null? lst) '())
    ((null? (cdr lst)) (list (car lst) (car lst)))
    (else
     (let ((mmtemp (minmax (cdr lst))) (first (car lst)))
       (cond
         ((> first (car mmtemp)) (cons first (cdr mmtemp)))
         ((< first (car mmtemp)) (list (car mmtemp) first))
         (else mmtemp))))))
```

If I enter:

```
(minmax '(3 4 6 9 22 203 1 43 8 4))
```

I get:

```
(203 3)
```

When I actually need:

```
(1 203)
```

I have no experience in Scheme and the lecture slides aren't helping. What needs to change to flip the output order and get the correct minimum value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the code in the `else` clause you get `mmtemp` which is a list with `car` being the biggest and `cadr` being the smallest. You then compare the current element with **only the biggest** to decide if you want to replace the biggest or the smallest. Thus your logic is faulty there.

To switch the place for smallest and biggest you just switch which element gets replaced.

Here is what I would have done:

```
(define (minmax lst)
  (define (helper lst min max)
    (if (null? lst) 
        (list min max) ; result is in min and max arguments
        (let ((cur (car lst)) (rest (cdr lst)))
          (cond ((<= min cur max) (helper rest min max)) ; correct order
                ((> cur max) (helper <??> <??> <??>))
                (else (helper <??> <??> <??>))))))

  (if (null? lst)
      #f ; or perhaps signal an error?
      (helper (cdr lst) (car lst) (car lst))))

(minmax '())        ; ==> #f 
(minmax '(5))       ; ==> (5 5)
(minmax '(4 2 5 1)) ; ==> (1 5)
```